# Sending facebook request via app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I read facebook document and implemented to my code but, request is not sending. I can't see request notification on website. I can see request ID on my Log screen.

Here is my part of code:
I took this code from developer.facebook.com

```
+ (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
    NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *val =
    [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    params[kv[0]] = val;
}
return params;
}

+(void) requestFriendMethod{

// Display the requests dialog
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"message"
 title:@"title"
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [AKFacebook parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
 }];

}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for answer and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook app id is same in both developer page and info in xcode next, enable sandbox mode and must fill canvas url [under app on facebook category] in developer page.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"Your friend facebook id";
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

    NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
    NSString *title = @"TITLE";

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                  message:message
                title:title
                parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                        if (error)
                    {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                        NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                    {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                        NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Request Sent. %@", params);
                    }
        }}];
```

Comment: I have tried this code before, but it also does not send request. Maybe as you said, it can be sandbox mode. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ya, check sandbox mode. if my answer helps you, upvote and accept.